# What is the best solution for creating a SOAP Server in PHP?

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

I need some advice on which library is the best choice when it comes to creating SOAP servers (and eventually SOAP clients) in PHP.

I know there is built-in functions for this, but is that really the best way to go about it?

Also, if you could attach some arguments as to why a certain library/method is the better, i'd be much delighted.

The only requirement i currently have (apart from the obvious client/server part) is that it can generate WSDL.

Does the WSDL version really matter at all? 1.1 or 2.0 what's the *real* difference/benefit of using 2.0?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would recommend looking at the [Zend_Soap](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.soap.html) class of Zend Framework.

Its fairly complete and robust and has been available in the framework long enough to have most if not all of its rough spots smoothed out. Plus its part of a framework that is being actively maintained so it will continue to support new standards and any bugs that are found will be fixed.

Comment: Do you know if it's possible to use it without using the framework? As a standalone solution?

Comment: Yes. Zend Framework emphasizes a use-at-will architecture that makes it possible to use only the parts of the framework that you want.

Comment: Will definitely give it a go then. I have only worked with the Zend Framework as a complete framework, didn't really know that you could pick out the favorite parts like that. Thanks for the input!

Comment: Found a tool to download separate classes with dependencies http://epic.codeutopia.net/pack/library/1.9

Answer (score 6):

I use PHP's built-in [SoapServer](http://php.net/manual/en/class.soapserver.php) class to serve requests because it's implemented in C so it's faster than any other class implemented in PHP (Zend, nusoap).

The limitation here is that SoapServer can't generate WSDL (as of May'11) so i am using [Zend SOAP Autodiscovery](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.soap.autodiscovery.html) to generate it.

Answer (score 1):

I use nuSoap: http://sourceforge.net/projects/nusoap/

Comment: What are the benefits would you say with nusoap compared to the other availablde solutions?

Comment: It's because I know only PHPSoap and NuSOAP, and as PHPSoap still not 100%
working well, I started using nusoap that was recommended in other forums that I saw a time ago. I never used ZendSoap, then would not know to tell if it's good or not, but would be interesting to test both to see which best serves you. NOTE: I use nusoap only as a server, to consume the WebService I use PHPSoap. I never had problems. Thank you.

Comment: Adding: ...I use nusoap only as a server, to consume the WebService I use PHPSoap, but you can use nuSoap for server and client.

Comment: Ah, thank you for the information. I'll check it out and see what i like best.

Comment: The one thing I see about NuSoap -- and someone correct me if I'm perceiving incorrectly -- but it appears that you end up doing double-logic to create the wsdl generation in NuSoap. As in, if you plan on populating models (objects) with the data received from Soap and create responses similarly from model structures, NuSoap defines it's output in parameters. So you are going to have to build your model(s) and then define them again in the new-soap params as well as convert the model properties to key/value pairs to feed them to nusoap